# What are the minimum dependencies and plugin configuration I need to create a web service client using Axis2 and Maven from a WSDL file?

Tags: java, web-services, maven-2, apache-axis, wsdl2code

I'm trying to create a web service client using Axis2.  I would like to use Maven 2 to generate the necessary classes from the WSDL I have but the documentation for the wsdl2code plugin isn't helping me.  Does anyone have a working example of a basic pom.xml that will generate classes from a WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888422/axis2-maven-example) can help you.

The [Axis2 code generation module](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-codegen/1.5.1) should be the main player in this and you can add a pom entry like the following for it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-codegen</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven transitive dependencies should then cover the rest.

Comment: I can't believe that worked.  How stupid is it that the documentation they provide doesn't even state this...  I was having all sorts of issues just building something it generated the code for.  Switching `axis2` to `axis2-codegen` solved the compilation issue...